# Print statements on server give IOError: failed to write data

Tags: python, pylons

I am running Pylons on my local machine with paster, and on a Debian server using WSGI. I want to add some print statements to debug a problem: am not a Pylons or Python expert.

On my local machine this works fine: print statements go to the terminal. On the server, the statements don't print to the log files: instead the log file says "IOError: failed to write data" whenever a print statement is called.

Until I can fix this, I can't debug anything on the server.

Could someone advise how to get printing running on the server? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use print statements, use the logging module. We can't help you without knowing the setup of the server.

Answer (score 3):

It's wrong for a WSGI application to use `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr`. If you want to spit debug to a server error log, use `environ['wsgi.errors'].write()`.